# React Native crash after running Android DEBUG build: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context

Tags: react-native

Just got a new M1 MBP from work. The app builds successfully, however, the app crashes immediately on launch when building for **debug**. Release builds launch without an issue.

I've gone through every file in the Android folder and I've compared it to a new RN project of the same version. Can't seem to find anything that would cause the app to not launch. The stack trace from the crash is below.

**Stack trace:**

```
--------- beginning of crash
2022-02-09 14:31:27.093 12685-12719/com.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.myApp, PID: 12685
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:239)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:268)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1371)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1065)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

**React Native Info**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 12.2
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Max
    Memory: 5.28 GB / 64.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.15 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 8.3.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.02.07.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111
    Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.2 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.66.3 => 0.66.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```